# Delay evaluation of an expression using std::future

Tags: c++, c++11, future, expression-templates

I have a class called `Expr` which uses expression template methodology, that could be used to build expressions like this:

```
Expr<int,Mat<int>> v(Mat<int>(10,10));
v(0,0)*3 + v(2,1)*v(1,2) >> val;
```

The expression is evaluated when `operator>>(T& val)` is called, i.e., when `>>` is encountered. Let us say that an `eval` function evaluates an expression, and is invoked inside `operator>>(T& val)`, which is defined in the `Expr` class:

```
void operator>>(T& val) { eval(val); }
```

Now, I want to further delay evaluation until user needs the result, by introducing futures. So, I modify `operator>>` as:

```
void operator>>(T& val) {
   handle_ = std::async(std::launch::deferred, [&val,this]() { eval(val);});
}
```

The issue is how/where to declare `std::future<void> handle_` so that we can easily access it later. At present it is declared globally, and I don't like it. Ideally, I would want to have the future as a member in `Expr` class, such that I can do this:

```
Expr<int,Mat<int>> v(Mat<int>(10,10));

v(0,0)*3 + v(2,1)*v(1,2) >> val;
... // other stuff
v.get(); // now, val can be accessed
```

Here, `v.get()` would internally call `handle_.get()`. However, this is incorrect, as the object that invoked `operator>>` is not stored anywhere, and I'm trying to call `get()` on a separate instance of `Expr`, which will lead to an error.

Please suggest.

Comment: Why can't the user do `auto expr = v(0,0)*3 + v(2,1)*v(1,2);` and then, when they need the actual result, `expr >> val;`? Why do you feel you need two layers of delayed evaluation?

Comment: This is actually part of an API, and I have to adhere to the way the original API was designed.

Comment: In what way does my suggestion break the original API?

Comment: The expression will have to be at the LHS of `>>`, and RHS to `>>` is where the expression result will go.

Comment: And, the statement - `v(0,0)*3 + v(2,1)*v(1,2) >> val;` must return immediately without evaluating the expression, so we can't have the actual result stored elsewhere.

Comment: What do you mean, without evaluating the expression? That calls `operator>>` which, you say, calls `eval`. If that doesn't evaluate the expression, then what does?

Comment: I want to delay the evaluation, that's why `operator>>` uses `async`, and an argument to `async` is `eval`. See how I have defined the modified `operator>>` in the question.

Comment: Why not delay evaluation simply by delaying the call to `operator>>` (and therefore to `eval`)? Why invent another wrapper?

Comment: As I said, I am bound by this design: `<expr> >> val;`, so `operator>>` gets called anyway. I can't avoid that. If there is any other way to delay call to `eval` then I can consider it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Is someone twisting your arm and forcing you to write `>>` on the same line as the rest of the expression? What do you mean by "bound"? What exactly will happen to you if you write `auto expr = v(0,0)*3 + v(2,1)*v(1,2); expr >> val;` instead?

Comment: It's just how the design is. `auto expr = v(0,0)*3 + v(2,1)*v(1,2); expr >> val;` will throw an error, because it is ill-formed w.r.t the API.

Comment: Have you tried it? What error message do you see?

Comment: It may emit an error like: `cannot deduce auto type`, but that's not the point. I really want to delay evaluation, either using futures, or by somehow delaying the call to `eval`.